# Doubt concerning Stochastic continuity

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I know that a stochastic process $X$ is said to be stochastically continuous if $\forall s$ $$\lim_{t\rightarrow s}\;P(|X(t)-X(s)|>a) = 0.$$. But then it is also true that stochastic continuity does not imply continuity of the sample paths. For example a Levy jump process is stochastically continuous. My doubt is that if I think about this definition it means that for any $\epsilon>0 $ and $\forall a >0$ we can find a $t$ close enough to $s$ such that $$P(|X(t)-X(s)|>a)<\epsilon $$
That is the proportion of sample paths where this can happen has a probability less than $\epsilon$. But then the jumps of size greater than $a$ can be allowed only on a small proportion of the sample paths .Then why  a Levy jump diffusion process can have  jumps on almost every path?
 This has been bothering me a lot. I am pretty sure my understanding here is very flawed. Thank for your help.

Comment: In the first equation is it also that a > 0?

Comment: @BCLC Yes IT IS

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure whether I fully understood what you are asking, but note that the limit you have must necessarily be from the right (i.e $\lim s \downarrow t$), so the paths are almost surely *right*-continuous. So how can the process have jumps on almost every path despite the condition? Well, look at for example the NIG process which has jumps at every instant but still has right-continuous paths by definition. Maybe the right-continuity is what is confusing you.

Comment: right continuity with left limits(consider a cumulative distribution function in the discrete case) can have jumps .

Comment: @user3503589 Well, yes, that was my point. So although you almost surely don't have right-discontinuity at any time point, you can have as many jumps as you want on the path of a Levy process

Comment: @user3503589 Also note that the stochastic-continuity condition has nothing to with the frequency of the jumps. That will be decided by the Levy measure.